# struct class and sysfs for a platform device/char device

Tags: linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

I have created a platform device driver that gets initialized from the device tree at boot time. I would like to be able to access this device as a char driver also and am trying to figure out which structure entries I should be using.

Basically I would like my device, which in the device tree uses resources starting at `0x34000000`, to show up as a char device in `/dev/myDevice`.

To do this I understand I need to register major and minor numbers using a `dev_t`.
1) Can I use the dev_t in platform_device->dev.devt, and if so do I still need to call `alloc_chrdev_region' or is it pre initialized by the kernel?

Currently I use it and I still call `alloc_chrdev_region` to initialize it, then I call `cdev_init`/`cdev_add` to create my char device.

Now my device shows up in /dev as /dev/34000000.myDevice.

2) Why does it show its memory resource in front of it?

After doing some reading, I decided to try to create a new class, and a new device (which doesn't seem right) In order to get a `/dev/myDevice` entry.

I see there is a `struct class *` field in `platform_device->dev.class`.

3) Do I need to initialize this field or is it pre-initialized by the kernel?

4) Why do I need to call `device_create` with the new 'struct class', when I already have a device initialized (`struct platform_device->dev`)

The connections between `dev_t`, `cdev`, `class`, and how they relate to the `platform_device` is a little bit of a maze to me. If someone would help explain, that would be great.

Comment: The `cdev_add & cdev_del` are low level char frameworks. They don't provide you a direct interface to create device nodes. Instead you must  use `class_create` and `device_create` to create device nodes manually. Else, if your device is bound to some of the framework such as input, tty, etc, then registering to that framework would create the device nodes automatically for you. Never directly mess with the fields of the the bus infrastructure.

Comment: Why then when I create PCIe modules do I only need to use cdev add and then mknod to create the device node?

Comment: `mknod` is a utility to create device nodes from "outside" the kernel modules. Whereas `class_create()` and `device_create()` also creates device nodes but, from "within" the kernel module. The preferred way is to use the second approach. So from your kernel code, you may call `class_create()` then `cdev_add()` and then `device_create()` in sequence.

Comment: I thought that udev was what actually calls mknod on those devices that were created using device_create? Does it not use rules to grab the Major and Minor numbers from sysfs and then calls mknod on them? If this were the case then mknod seems to be required in both situations.

Comment: Yes. You are right. But, as a developer you need not worry about the internals. It will be taken care automatically. You need not call mknod explicitly while using `class_create()` and `device_create()`